# How does exactly android's push notification work?

Tags: android, push-notification

Just wondering how does android's push notification work. Is android phone constantly checking with server or something else?

Comment: Once I read it's a constant data stream between server and client. Like a YouTube video. But with very low bandwidth and probably other techniques to save data and battery.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that it uses existing connections towards Google & Co, keeping it at a sound level. At least if I've interpreted it correctly. :)

Comment: possible dup of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508613/how-push-notification-technology-works-in-android-is-it-through-polling-or-some)

Comment: Here are [the Google I|O 2012 video about GCM](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YoaP6hcDctM) and [the Google I|O 2010 video about its C2DM precursor](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLM4LajwDVc).

Comment: @BilltheLizard: if you closed this question as "not real", you might want to close its duplicate too, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508613/how-push-notification-technology-works-in-android-is-it-through-polling-or-some