# Android Push notification: How does Google Play Services Connect to Google Server

Tags: android, push-notification, google-play-services

I am trying to understand the Android push notifications in deep.

As per this question,
[How does push notification technology work on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508613/how-does-push-notification-technology-work-on-android)

There is an active TCP connection maintained by Google Play Services to Google servers. I am not able to find out this TCP connection.

I used an app called [NetStat Plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rinacode.android.netstatplus) to enumerate the TCP connections and this is what I came up with:

I have lots of GCM enabled apps but none of the connection here seems to be to Google servers.

[image]

Comment: I installed this application also, and I do see lot's of connections made from google play process, so I don't know why you don't see them from your device..     anyway - you can be sure that such connection exists.  there is no "hidden magic"  that push without any connection a message to the device.

Comment: I understand. I just want to see such connection existing.

Comment: this may not be the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198572/building-an-android-notification-server/25198855#25198855) your looking for but just look and see. 
Actually im referring to your question : `How does push notification technology work on Android?`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, first don't choose tab "ALL", choose "ESTABLISHED" to get rid of not currently available connections. Here is a screenshot from my device:
[image: Screenshot]

There is an entry called "system" which adresses IP 173.194.65.95. If you execute a whois-query like the following
[image: whois]

you will see that this is a Google server. Try to enter the IP in your browser (SO doesn't allow to set links on IP-Adresses).

But the system connection is not always there. When you look at u0_a19 you will also see a Google server. This connection is always there and might have a different name on your system. On your screen shot I see `u0_a7` which points to a Google server.

When I execute `ps | grep u0_a19` in a [terminal window](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) I get:

- com.google.process.location
- com.google.process.gapps
- com.google.android.gms

`com.google.android.gms` are the [Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html) so it seems that there is one connection shared for different purposes and one of them might be the push notification.

Answer (score 2):

Set up a "lab" like this:

Internet <--> your router <--> your pc <--> your Android device.

[Create an "ad-hoc" wi-fi connection](http://lifehacker.com/5369381/turn-your-windows-7-pc-into-a-wireless-hotspot), so your pc will act as an access point and will be connected to internet.

Connect the Android device to the new connection, not directly to the router.

Use a tool like [TcpDump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to monitor the messages passing from Google Play and your phone.

More options are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555403/capturing-mobile-phone-traffic-on-wireshark), if you want to root your phone.