# Building an Android notification server

Tags: android, android-notifications

Is there any documentation on how to build a custom notification server for Android? I am currently using GCM but due to the nature of the app and the fact that notifications are a very important feature in my app, I would rather implement this service internally so that I can control the throughput and not have any artificial limitations (even if it's hundreds of thousands of notifications per day). I also would like to use the same notification server later on with the iOS version of the app and for that reason, a custom built notification server is much preferred.

I would ideally like to know what's involved in order to write a similar messaging system (on the Android front-end). To further clarify, I would like to understand how (on top level) the GCM notification internally works on Android and how to replicate that functionality on my own.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for the last 3 months I feel the same way as you do.

1, you should read this first [mqtt](http://mqtt.org/).

2, and give yourself 1 hour of watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-KNPXPmx88E)

3, theres alot of examples out [there](http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=1599) on how to integrate [client](http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=1599) and over [here](http://activemq.apache.org/) for the [server](http://activemq.apache.org/).

EDIT: some success stories [here](http://mqtt.org/2011/08/mqtt-used-by-facebook-messenger) from facebook.

Its worth a shot. :) hope this will help you :)

Comment: Wow, This is amazing! Thank you very much. I already knew a little about MQTT. I'll try to implement the ActiveMQ (thankfully they have a C# wrapper since my server is fully written in C# running on Mono) and test the client code you've linked. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think [Pushwoosh](http://www.pushwoosh.com) does exactly what you want to do. There also exists [UrbanAirship](http://www.urbanairship.com), but unlike Pushwoosh UrbanAirship's service isn't free.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is not what I was looking for. I would like to implement my own version for notifications and not use a third party notification service. Many thanks for your reply nonetheless. Much appreciate the effort and the fact you took the time to reply.

Comment: In this case you will need to implement both [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) and [Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) on your server. It isn't possible to implement only one of both and access the Push Notification service of the other platform.

Comment: I think there's a confusion here. I would like to write MY OWN notification server, i.e. implement something that performs the same operations that GCM and APNS do without using those services. If you read the comment that was flagged as an answer, you will see what I mean. Thank you.

Comment: Oops, seems like I understood your question wrong. Sorry :/