# What is the best way to implement push server-side app for android?

Tags: java, android, sockets, server-side

I'm developing an Android app that requires 2 (or more) devices to communicate with each other.
I tried using `Google Cloud Messaging` but I was disappointed to find out that the `GCM` max capacity is 100 messages, so it is broken and does not fit my requirements.

I was thinking about `java sockets`. Every device will open a new socket (or keep its socket open) and communicate with a group of sockets (devices).

In order to communicate this way I need a server-side app that can send messages to the client (android device). So I figured out that `HTTP` or web-service won't help me. Am I right?

What is the best way for me to implement such a server-side app?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this question I previously asked and implemented. It was for implementing my own Notification mechanism but it equally (or even more) applies to chatting applications since message queues perfectly fit that usecase.

[Building an Android notification server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198572/building-an-android-notification-server)

I ended up not doing it and using GCM at the end but **I did have a fully working solution using ActiveMQ and Paho**. You can research them both and understand their inner workings. It's easy in principle and definitely possible but the problem is, you may not be able to do this for `iOS` or `WP` as it requires running a service in the background (in case your app is not open and you want to make sure the messages are at least sent in a notification).

The possible solution to that problem would be to use both the notification service (GCM or equivalent) for background notifications and then using your MQ for actual communication but I decided that was too much for my project.

If you look at Paho, it will have a fully working MQTT solution that will work even if the phone is not "online" (sleeping or otherwise) and there are plenty of samples for ActiveMQ and drivers for multiple programming languages.

I think this solution is much better than having open sockets between two apps, at least because they allow you to persist messages and guarantee delivery which is an important aspect for a chatting application.

Answer (score 0):

As it is said by kha, choose one of the message queue protocols is the best solution. 3 reasons in brief,

1. Delivery guaranteed regardless of temporary offline or long latency.
2. As simple as subscribe / publish, no worry about transport layer any more.
3. Broker available online. You save time and money for setting up your own.

For mobile devices like in your case, I'd prioritize MQTT too. It's lightweight and stable. If you are totally new to message queue or MQTT, refer to this [documentaion](http://robomq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/MQTT/) and [example code](https://github.com/robomq/robomq.io/tree/master/sdk/MQTT)