# Push notification from local API in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am having an API locally hosted in one of the servers (LAN). What I am looking to understand if it is feasible to enable push notification from the server in case of a record entry. Every time a post request is made to the local server, Is it possible to push a notification to a certain mobile device? Please note, I am not considering push notification from web services such as google, Azure, Firebase etc.

Comment: FCM/GCM, APN & WNS are integrated into the OS and iOS/Android/Windows do not support replacing those with a private push notification system. Depending upon the OS and the app requirements, you could look at a persistent socket connection to a server from your app (like WebSockets, etc...) and then publish data events to the devices (like a "non-visual" real-time chat application).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is feasible.**

As Sushi said, you can use `WebSockets` or other Sockets to keep connect between Apps and Server. When client connected to your server, server will record which app is connecting.

By the way, you can custom notification's url between server and app.Use some special characters to distinguish between your various parameters, such as &/[ ]. You are free to set the header and body style of the message. Also, when your message needs to be encrypted, some encryption methods can be used.

Here is a similar discussion about [Building an Android notification server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198572/building-an-android-notification-server) can be refer .

Comment: This is a nice article, but what it doesn't support xamarin forms.

Comment: @ARH Yeah , this is not for xamarin forms ,just a reference . The focus is on the server setup. As for the notification, it only needs to format the message with the server. The client connection can be received.