# Push notifications from server to client [Java]

Tags: java, server, client, push

Is there anyway to send a push notification from a server to the client so that it appears on the screen if the client is minimized?

Answer (score 0):

on stackoverflow you sould be very specific while asking questions.

ask you question more clearly by adding explanation for what you have done (programmed / scripted) and what you want to achieve and what are you getting.

as far as i have understood your question here is what i have to say:
in simple, the answer is there cannot be a decelerate push until client listens. it doesn't work that way.

here you would get more info, how push notification works -  'https://stackoverflow.com/a/11508811/2173890'

OR

instead of "always ON" port, you could write script on the client side to read the message on server on particular interval or an event.

e.g.
if you write a program that will read the specific message on server when you minimize the client (application) the client will show the notification.