# Push Notification in Asp.net Webform or mvc using google cloud messaging

Tags: c#, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

[How does push notification technology work on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508613/how-does-push-notification-technology-work-on-android)

i have read this post on stack over flow, how push notification works on android. Currently, am working on client server application( chat) can  i use same push notification in my web client? or can i achieve push notification through google cloud messaging?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to get push notification, you will still need to use the [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) to send the notification using the ASP.NET and C#.

I found this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339162/Android-push-notification-implementation-using-ASP) that can help you on how to integrate a push notification service for Android using ASP.NET and C#. This tutorial has a step by step process that can explain you on how to send push notification including Authentication Process, Server Certification and Send Message. It also contains sample code that you can follow.

For more information, check also this [ASP.Net Mobile Push Gateway Tutorial for Realtime Apps](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/asp-dot-net-c-sharp/mobile-gateway)