# Wants to make push notification app like WhatsApp

Tags: php, android, android-studio, push-notification

I want to make an App with push notifications, which will not stop in Android phone, exactly like in WhatsApp.

I can easily make a php API for notification on my xyz web hosting to send push notifications to my application.

But I don't know which methodology to use. I am a beginner in Android App development. I want to make the App using Android Studio.

I appreciated if you could share any example source code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does push notification technology work on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508613/how-does-push-notification-technology-work-on-android)

Answer (score -2):

In this case using google fire base is a good choice.search about it.