# What is the best option for Android and iOS apps to notify user without using a third party?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, push-notification, usernotifications

I am starting my second app and one of the requirements of the customer is that users will receive a notification when they should make a new appointment or purchase new maintenance products for their medical instruments.

Since this is an app with medical (so very personal) information I'd like to avoid using third party services. The notifications must always been shown, even when the app is not active. So I was looking for push notifications but those seem (always) to rely on third party cloud services.

One option is to simply create an agenda item with an alarm, but are there other, more elegant ways to get the user's attention, even if the app is not running?

Comment: *"rely on third party cloud services"*, are google and apple a 3rd party in your scenario? Because they both offer APIs you can interact with to create push notifications. *If* you consider those 3rd parties and do not want to interact with them you are out of luck...

Comment: Yes, I was hoping that this is possible without Google and Apple.

Comment: May be you have to implement a server with socket connections . Please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/11508811/3995126 (that's how google is providing Push notificaiton)

Comment: If you do not want to use push notifications then you are out of luck. If you do not trust the system you are running on then there is not much you can do at all, can you even store user data if you do not trust android / google to sniff around in it?